# Why are overriden init(rootViewController) and init(nibName, bundle) required in UINavigationController subclass?

Tags: swift

I have created a custom `UINavigationController`:

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override public init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    }

    public override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

}
```

Then I create a subclass:

```
final class CustomNavigationController: NavigationController {}
```

But I get a runtime error:

> fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class 'CustomNavigationController'

I have been told that this happens because these `init()` act like convenience initializers and I have to implement them in the subclass to avoid the crash.

I don't understand this statement since I tried something simple:

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
    convenience init(tenYearsOldNamed name: String) {
        self.init(name: name, age: 10)
    }
}

class SubPerson: Person {}

let ben = SubPerson(tenYearsOldNamed: "Ben")
```

This works fine no matter I override the `init(name, age)` in `SubPerson` or not.

So I don't really understand what's happening with those `UINavigationController` inits.

Thanks for your help.